# Does the product of two weakly converging measures converge weakly?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $\mu_n,\nu_n$ be sequences of (probability) measures on $E,\mathcal E $ and $F,\mathcal F$ that converge weakly to $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively. Does the product measure $\mu_n \times \nu_n$ on $E\times F,\sigma(\mathcal E,\mathcal F)$ converge weakly to $\mu \times \nu$?

Intuitively, I'd say it does converge. I try to prove it by showing that for every continuous bounded function $f(x,y)$ on $E\times F$, the expectation converges. To do so I'd like to argue that every such $f$ can be approximated in some sense by a function of the form
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i f_i(x)g_i(y).$$

I believe I need this approximation to be such that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $k$ such that
$$ \int | f-\sum_{i=1}^k f_ig_i| (\mu_n\times \nu_n) <\epsilon$$
for all $n$ and 
$$ \int | f-\sum_{i=1}^k f_ig_i| (\mu\times \nu) <\epsilon$$
but that seems to require a lot from the approximation. Is that always possible or does it only work for compact spaces $E$ and $F$?

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue  that $\mu_n\times\nu_n$ was tight, and then I'd show that only the desired product measure can be a subsequence's limit distribution.

A putative misbehaving limit measure would have continuous bounded $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ "witnesses" you can control because you have independence all along the way, and free use of DCT.